# why i cant print using 'tostring' ? how can i print arry that includes classes in it?

Tags: java, tostring

public String toString() { // this is in anther class

```
    String Cubes = "+";

    for(int i = 0; i < CubesStack.length;) {
        Cubes = Cubes + CubesStack[i].toString();
    }

    return "maxCubes = " + this.maxCubes + "\n" +

            "currentCubes = " + this.currentCubes + "\n" + 

            "CubesStack = " + Cubes; 

}
```

public class MainMain { // this is main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cubesTower tower1 = new cubesTower(20);
    System.out.println(tower1.toString());
}
```

}

why i cant print using 'tostring' ? how can i print arry that includes classes in it ?  thank you very much .

Comment: Implement `toString()` for your object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 1):

Your object should implement **toString()** method other wise it will take default implementation of toString() from **java.lang.Object**.

java.lang.Object default implementation is

```java
public String toString() {
   return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So you have to override the toString() to get your own values

**For Example:**
Here I have **Name** class which will have two properties

```java
class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Name[] names = new Name[]{new Name("john","doe"),new Name("john1","doe1")};
    System.out.println(names[0]);
}
```

If I don't override toString() then **output**: com.stackovflow.problems.Name@33909752

After implementing toString() **output**: Name [firstName=john, lastName=doe]